# MongoDB: Updating an average in a document with 2 nested arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following MongoDB document:

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    company_name: "Name",
    registered: 2/21/2015 2:00,
    trucks: [
        {
            truck_id: "TEB7622",
            weight: 88.33,
            capacity: 273.333,
            length: 378.333,
            width: 377.383,
            average_grade: 2.5,
            grades: [
                {
                    grade_number: 4,
                    timestamp: 2/21/2015 2:00
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            truck_id: "TEB5572",
            weight: 854.33,
            capacity: 2735.333,
            length: 378.333,
            width: 37.383,
            average_grade: 3.8,
            grades: [
                {
                    grade_number: 4,
                    timestamp: 2/21/2015 2:00
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

I want to update each truck's `average_grade` by adding all the `grade_numbers`. The problem I'm having is that the `grade_numbers` I am trying to add are in an array within an array. I have tried using `$unwind` to unwind both trucks and grades arrays.

This is the query I have tried using:

```js
db.col.aggregate([ 
   {$unwind: "$trucks"}, 
   {$unwind: "$trucks.grades"}, 
   { $project: { 
      "_id": "$trucks.truck_id", 
      "trucks.average_grade": { $avg: { $sum: "trucks.grades.grade_number"} } 
      } 
   }])
```

Do I have to add something more to my query? I want to update ALL of the `trucks.average_grades`, since there a lot of them in the document I am trying to update.

Comment: you cannot use aggregation to update a document

Comment: @Michael9 So then I need to run two queries right? One to get the averages and one to update the averages? Do I have to store the averages on another "variable"?

Comment: Double nested arrays are not a good idea if you need to query the data inside them. They are ok if the data is just for display. Perhaps you should reconsider the data model? Maybe each truck should be its own document, with a `company_id` field? Or each grade its own document? You do not want to rely on a double unwind aggregation pipeline for a normal query, so I would not recommend the below solution unless the query is uncommon.

Comment: @wdberkeley Wouldn't that make it kind of like a relational database? I'm new to MongoDB, so this is the first time I've actually modeled a document database. I'm just using this query a couple of times (the actual calculation will be made in Hadoop).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `aggregation` to update a document, but you can definitely use it to get the data you want to use for an update. First of all, I noticed that there are some `{}` missing around your `grade` object inside the `grades` array. You might want to double check that your document structure is as posted. Secondly, there are a couple of issues with your aggregation query.

1. The `$avg` operator works inside a `$group` clause, not a `$project`.
2. When you use `$avg`, you do not need to use `$sum`.
3. You want to average `trucks.grades.grade.grade_number`, which actually holds the numeric value of the grade. That is, you are missing `grade` between `grades` and `grade_number`.

If you resolve those issues, you get a query similar to the following:

```js
db.col.aggregate([ 
    { "$unwind": "$trucks" }, 
    { "$unwind": "$trucks.grades" }, 
    { "$group":
        { 
            "_id": "$trucks.truck_id", 
            "average_grade": { "$avg": "$trucks.grades.grade_number" } 
        } 
    }
]);
```

For your sample document, that returns:

```js
{ "_id" : "TEB5572", "average_grade" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "TEB7622", "average_grade" : 4 }
```

Now you can use this information to update the `average_grade` field. If you're using MongoDB version 2.6 or higher, the `aggregate` method will return a cursor. You can iterate through that cursor and update the documents accordingly.

In this example, I search for documents that have a particular `truck_id` inside their `trucks` array and proceed to update the `average_grade` with the one computed by the aggregation query. You can modify it to suit your needs. Combined with the aggregation query, the code looks like this.

```js
// Get average grade for each truck and assign results to cursor.
var cur = db.col.aggregate([ 
    { "$unwind": "$trucks" }, 
    { "$unwind": "$trucks.grades" }, 
    { "$group":
        { 
            "_id": "$trucks.truck_id", 
            "average_grade": { "$avg": "$trucks.grades.grade_number" } 
        } 
    }
]);

// Iterate through results and update average grade for each truck.
while (cur.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cur.next();
    db.col.update({ "trucks.truck_id": doc._id },
                  { "$set": { "trucks.$.average_grade": doc.average_grade }},
                  { "multi": true});
}
```