# Updating nested array inside array mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, api

I have the following mongodb document structure:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "04",
        "name": "test service 4",
        "id": "04",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "title": "testing",
        "description": "test",
        "protocol": "test",
        "operations": [
            {
                "_id": "99",
                "oName": "test op 52222222222",
                "sid": "04",
                "name": "test op 52222222222",
                "oid": "99",
                "description": "testing",
                "returntype": "test",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "oName": "Param1",
                        "name": "Param1",
                        "pid": "011",
                        "type": "582",
                        "description": "testing",
                        "value": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "oName": "Param2",
                        "name": "Param2",
                        "pid": "012",
                        "type": "58222",
                        "description": "testing",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have been able to use $elemMatch in order to update fields in operations, but when I try to do the same thing (modified) for parameters it does not seem to work. I was wondering what other approach should I look into trying in order to be able to successfully update fields in a specific parameter, looking it up by its pid.

The update code I currently have and does not work looks like this:

```
var oid = req.params.operations;
var pid = req.params.parameters;

collection.update({"parameters":{"$elemMatch": {"pid": pid}}},{"$set": {"parameters.$.name":req.body.name, "parameters.$.description": req.body.description,"parameters.$.oName": req.body.oName,"parameters.$.type": req.body.type} }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error updating service: ' + err);
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
        } else {
            // console.log('' + result + ' document(s) updated');
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support matching into more than one level of an array. Consider altering your document model so each document represents an operation, with information common to a set of operations duplicated in the operation documents.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### MongoDB 3.6 and newer

With MongoDB 3.6 and above comes a new feature that allows you to update nested arrays by using [the positional filtered `$\[<identifier>\]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) syntax in order to match the specific elements and apply different conditions through [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) in the update statement:

```
const { oid, pid } = req.params;
const { name, oName, description, type } = req.body; 

collection.update(
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "operations": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                oid, "parameters.pid": pid
            }
        }
    },
    { "$set": { 
        "operations.$[outer].parameters.$[inner].name": name,
        "operations.$[outer].parameters.$[inner].description": description,
        "operations.$[outer].parameters.$[inner].oName": oName,
        "operations.$[outer].parameters.$[inner].type": type 
    } },
    { "arrayFilters": [
        { "outer.oid": oid },
        { "inner.pid": pid }
    ] }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error updating service: ' + err);
        res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
    } else {
        // console.log('' + result + ' document(s) updated');
        res.send(result);
    }
});
```

---

### For MongoDB 3.4 and older:

As @wdberkeley mentioned in his comment:

> MongoDB doesn't support matching into more than one level of an array.
>   Consider altering your document model so each document represents an
>   operation, with information common to a set of operations duplicated
>   in the operation documents.

I concur with the above and would recommend redesigning your schema as MongoDB engine does not support multiple positional operators ( See **[Multiple use of the positional `$` operator to update nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855246/multiple-use-of-the-positional-operator-to-update-nested-arrays)**)

However, if you know the index of the operations array that has the parameters object to be updated beforehand then the update query will be:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        "_id" : "04", 
        "operations.parameters.pid": "011"
    }, 
    {
        "$set": { 
            "operations.0.parameters.$.name": "foo",
            "operations.0.parameters.$.description": "bar", 
            "operations.0.parameters.$.type": "foo" 
        }
    }
)
```

**EDIT:**

If you would like to create the **`$set`** conditions on the fly i.e. something which would help you get the indexes for the objects and then modify accordingly, then consider using **[MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)**.

Currently this seems to be not possible using the aggregation framework. There is an unresolved open **[JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4588.)** linked to it. However, a workaround is possible with **[MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)**. The basic idea with MapReduce is that it uses JavaScript as its query language but this tends to be fairly slower than the aggregation framework and should not be used for real-time data analysis.

In your MapReduce operation, you need to define a couple of steps i.e. the mapping step (which maps an operation into every document in the collection, and the operation can either do nothing or emit some object with keys and projected values) and reducing step (which takes the list of emitted values and reduces it to a single element).

For the map step, you ideally would want to get for every document in the collection, the index for each `operations` array field and another key that contains the `$set` keys.

Your reduce step would be a function (which does nothing) simply defined as `var reduce = function() {};`

The final step in your MapReduce operation will then create a separate collection operations that contains the emitted operations array object along with a field with the `$set` conditions. This collection can be updated periodically when you run the MapReduce operation on the original collection.
Altogether, this MapReduce method would look like:

```
var map = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.operations.length; i++){
        emit( 
            {
                "_id": this._id, 
                "index": i 
            }, 
            {
                "index": i, 
                "operations": this.operations[i],            
                "update": {
                    "name": "operations." + i.toString() + ".parameters.$.name",
                    "description": "operations." + i.toString() + ".parameters.$.description",
                    "type": "operations." + i.toString() + ".parameters.$.type"
                }                    
            }
        );
    }
};

var reduce = function(){};

db.collection.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    {
        "out": {
            "replace": "operations"
        }
    }
);
```

Querying the output collection `operations` from the MapReduce operation will typically give you the result:

```
db.operations.findOne()
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : "03",
        "index" : 0
    },
    "value" : {
        "index" : 0,
        "operations" : {
            "_id" : "96",
            "oName" : "test op 52222222222",
            "sid" : "04",
            "name" : "test op 52222222222",
            "oid" : "99",
            "description" : "testing",
            "returntype" : "test",
            "parameters" : [ 
                {
                    "oName" : "Param1",
                    "name" : "foo",
                    "pid" : "011",
                    "type" : "foo",
                    "description" : "bar",
                    "value" : ""
                }, 
                {
                    "oName" : "Param2",
                    "name" : "Param2",
                    "pid" : "012",
                    "type" : "58222",
                    "description" : "testing",
                    "value" : ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "update" : {
            "name" : "operations.0.parameters.$.name",
            "description" : "operations.0.parameters.$.description",
            "type" : "operations.0.parameters.$.type"
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use the cursor from the `db.operations.find()` method to iterate over and update your collection accordingly:

```
var oid = req.params.operations;
var pid = req.params.parameters;
var cur = db.operations.find({"_id._id": oid, "value.operations.parameters.pid": pid });

// Iterate through results and update using the update query object set dynamically by using the array-index syntax.
while (cur.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cur.next();
    var update = { "$set": {} };
    // set the update query object
    update["$set"][doc.value.update.name] = req.body.name;
    update["$set"][doc.value.update.description] = req.body.description;
    update["$set"][doc.value.update.type] = req.body.type;

    db.collection.update(
        {
            "_id" : oid, 
            "operations.parameters.pid": pid
        }, 
        update 
    );
};
```

Comment: This does work, but is there any way for me to create the $set conditions on the fly? Something which would help me get the indexes for the objects and then modify accordingly?

Comment: I was wondering if by any chance it was possible for me to implement something like what they suggest here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756041/mongodb-updating-an-average-in-a-document-with-2-nested-arrays

Comment: @SantiagoEsquivel Quite possible. Will provide the solution later on but essentially use MapReduce to obtain a projection with the array indexes and use those index values from that projection to update the array elements on the fly.

Comment: Ok, I have been trying to replicate what they explain in that answer but have not found much success. Ill keep trying and hopefully Ill be close to what your solution is, if you have time later today to answer it. Thanks again.

Comment: @SantiagoEsquivel I've updated the answer to include the MapReduce solution oriented approach.

Comment: Watchout! "operations.0.parameters.$.name": "foo", >> this will set the parameter for matching operations index matched from "operations.parameters.pid": "011" (seems like that position is operations.0) instead of using the parameter index matching parameters.pid. –Fix:"operations.parameters.pid": "011 should turn into ["operations.0.parameters.pid": "011]

Answer (score 3):

If it is data that is changed frequently, you should flatten the structure and separate the data that changes a lot from that which does not.

If it is data that does not change often, and the entire data object is not massive, just modify the object client-side, and update the entire object.

Answer (score 1):

We will try to find index of outer array(i) and inner array(j)and then update

```js
collection.findById(04)
.then(result =>{
    for(let i = 0; i<result.operations.length; i++){
        if(result.operation[i]._id == "99"){
            let parameters = result.operations[i].parameters;`enter code here`
            for(let j = 0; j<parameters.length; j++){
                if(parameters[j].pid == "011"){
                    console.log("i", i);
                    console.log("j", j);
                    let data = {}
                    data["operations." + i + ".parameters." + j + ".oName"] = updateoName
                    data["operations." + i + ".parameters." + j + ".name"] = updatename
                    data["operations." + i + ".parameters." + j + ".pid"] = updatepid
                    data["operations." + i + ".parameters." + j + ".description"] = updatedescription
                    data["operations." + i + ".parameters." + j + ".value"] = updatevalue
                    console.log(data)
                    collection.update({
                        "_id": "04"
                    },{
                        $set: data
                    })
                    .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with mongo version 3.6 you can use the **$[]** in Conjunction with **$[]** to Update Nested Arrays

> **Update Nested Arrays in Conjunction with $[]**
>
> The $[] filtered positional operator, in conjunction with
>   all $[] positional operator can be used to update nested arrays.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#position-nested-arrays-filtered