# MongoDB delete element from array

Tags: mongodb

I want to delete element in array

Here I find such element of array

```
db.getCollection('files').aggregate([{'$unwind': "$Package.PackageBody.InvestmentVehicle"},{'$match': { "Package.PackageBody.InvestmentVehicle.Name": "file.txt"}}])
```

It's better in one command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an element from an array of an array in MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507696/delete-an-element-from-an-array-of-an-array-in-mongodb)

Comment: @user1211 thank will read

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it delete element of array, but unfortunately leave NULL ,instead of total delete.

```
db.getCollection('typeE').update(
    { "Package.PackageBody.InvestmentVehicle.Operation.LegalName": "FileName" },
    {
        "$unset": {
            "Package.PackageBody.InvestmentVehicle.$": ""
        }
    },false,true
)
```