# How to delete an element of an array from Mongodb [Angular]

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

This question doesn't answer my question:
[Delete an element from an array of an array in MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507696/delete-an-element-from-an-array-of-an-array-in-mongodb)

I've created a very basic MEAN application. I'm creating (or trying to create) a stackoverflow kind of mechanism. I've an article on which there are upvotes and downvotes. Here's a screenshot of mongodb record. There are many such records:
[image]

You can see there's an array of `upvoters` and `downvoters`. I've a case where the current logged in user who previously upvoted an article now wants to downvote the same article. Then his name should be shifted from 'upvoters' array to `downvoters` array. This involves two steps:

1. Delete current logged in user from `upvoters` array
2. Add same user in `downvoters` array.

Step no. 2 I can do. But step 1 I'm facing problem with. Here's my code. Focus on `removeUserFromUpvotersList()` method:

**article.component.ts**

```
    export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
      articleId : String = '';
      article;      

      currentLoggedInUserId: string;    

      updatedVotes={
        articleid: "",
        upvotes: 0,
        downvotes: 0,
        upvoters: [],
        downvoters: []
      };

      ...

      downvoted() {
        console.log("downvoted");
        this.removeUserFromUpvotersList();
      }

      removeUserFromUpvotersList() {
        this.updatedVotes.upvoters.push(localStorage.getItem('userid'));
        this._articleService.removeUserFromUpvotersList(this.updatedVotes, localStorage.getItem('userid'))
        .subscribe (
          res => {
          },
          err => console.log(err)
        );
      }
    }
```

**article.service.ts**

```
export class ArticleService {
  ...
  private _deleteFromUpvotersListURL = "http://localhost:3000/api/remove-from-upvoters-list";
  ...

  removeUserFromUpvotersList(updatedArticle, id) {
    return this.http.delete<any>(this._deleteFromUpvotersListURL+'/'+id, updatedArticle);
  }
}
```

**api.ts**

```
router.delete('/remove-from-upvoters-list/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log("removing from upvoters list");
    let userId = req.params.id;
    let articleId = req.body.articleid;
    Article.update({ articleid: articleId }, { $pull: { upvoters: userId } }).then(opResult => console.log(opResult));
    Article.deleteOne({ userId: userId }, (error, userId) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            if (!article) {
                res.status(401).send('something went wrong')
            } else {
                console.log('successfully deleted');
            }
        }
    })
})
```

I know my api is working fine because I'm able to perform add and update operations. Please help me with delete.

Answer (score 1):

In frontend you call the put method and the backend endpoint is delete.
Changing to http.delete in frontend service should fix the problem.

Comment: Nice catch David. I changed it to delete. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Do you get something logged in the backend application?

Comment: Yes. Userid and password.

Comment: If the deletion is successful you dont respond something. You can use `res.sendStatus(200)`

Comment: The deletion itself is not successful. That's what my question is.