# Update nested array element in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, typescript, multidimensional-array

In my case I have mongodb document with nested arrays and I need to update attributes array elements. My mongodb document as follows.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5dca9c5ece5b91119746eece"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-20T11:48:55.339Z"),
"attributeSet" : [ 
    {
        "attributeSetName" : "test-0",
        "type" : "Product",
        "id" : "1574158032603",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-19T10:10:53.783Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-19T10:07:20.084Z"),
        "attributes" : [ 
            {
                "attributeName" : "test-attribute",
                "defaultValue" : 123,
                "isRequired" : false,
                "id" : "1574221129398"
            }, 
            {
                "attributeName" : "test-attribute-02",
                "defaultValue" : 456,
                "isRequired" : false,
                "id" : "1574250533840"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "attributeSetName" : "test-1",
        "type" : "Product",
        "id" : "1574158116355",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-19T10:08:37.251Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-19T10:08:37.251Z"),
        "attributes" : []
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to update element in attributes array and get the updates document into result object. This is what I tried so far.

```
const result = await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
{
    _id: settingsToBeUpdated._id,
    "attributeSet": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "attributeSet.id": attributeSetId,
            "attributes": {
                $elemMatch: {
                    'attributes.id': id
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $set: {
        'attributeSet.$[outer].attributes.$[inner].attributeName': attributeDto.attributeName,
        'attributeSet.$[outer].attributes.$[inner].defaultValue': attributeDto.defaultValue,
        'attributeSet.$[outer].attributes.$[inner].isRequired': attributeDto.isRequired,
    }
},
{
    "arrayFilters": [
        { "outer.id": attributeSetId },
        { "inner.id": id }
    ]
}
);
```

It does not update the model. I refered to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634150/updating-nested-array-inside-array-mongodb), but it does not help.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Please update the question with actual sample documents (not images) and desired o/p structure to have better visibility on context and get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of rectification required on the query, otherwise its almost there. The update is not working because `$elemMatch` for `attributeSet` (array of docs) field is to happen on **`id`** property of those docs to filter and not on **attributeSet.id**, it woudn't figure what it is. And nested elemMatch is not required, **simply use dot notation**.

To debug you can try it out with a find query.

**Query (Shell):**

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: settingsToBeUpdated._id,
    attributeSet: {
      $elemMatch: {
        id: attributeSetId,
        "attributes.id": id
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "attributeSet.$[as].attributes.$[a].attributeName":
        attributeDto.attributeName,
      "attributeSet.$[as].attributes.$[a].defaultValue":
        attributeDto.defaultValue,
      "attributeSet.$[as].attributes.$[a].isRequired": attributeDto.isRequired
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [{ "as.id": attributeSetId }, { "a.id": id }],
    returnNewDocument: true
  }
);
```