# $addToSet in nested array

Tags: mongodb

I need to perform a `$addToSet` on an nested array, here an example:

```
{
   _id: 123,
   posts:[
      {
         _id: 234,
         userid: 123 //its same id like the documents id,
         likesUser: []
      }
   ]
}
```

My API requires 2 parameters:

1. The ID of the document, and the Post ID in witch post i want to add.
2. The ID of the user that liked that post.

If a user likes an Post his User ID should be stored in `likesUser`.

Lets say a user likes a post. The document have the id `123`, first i want to search the document with that ID. After that i want to search the post with the id `234`. Now i want to store the ID of the users that liked the post in `likesUser`, in this case the user have the ID `5d345`

```
{
   _id: 123,
   posts:[
      {
         _id: 234,
         userid: 123 //its same id like the documents id,
         likesUser: ["5d345"]
      }
   ]
}
```

How do i archieve it? I have tried it with `$elemMatch` but it doesnt work it throws me error over error.

Comment: $arrayFilter should help, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953960/update-nested-array-element-in-mongodb

Comment: @Joe thank you i will check it out and try it on mongodb playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the result:

```
 let result = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),
      "posts._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(postId)
    },
    {
      $addToSet: {
        "posts.$.likesUser": USER
      }
    }
  );
```